# Using Bibtex within an article

Tags: bibtex

I like using bibtex for generating my bibliography since it takes care of all the formatting for me. I'm wondering if/how it is possible to easily insert bibliographic information into other parts of an article or document. For instance, if I wanted to easily update the publication list in my CV, or for listing my publications in a grant proposal. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: [Welcome to Tex.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  You can use BibTeX in an article as you would in other classes. If you have an appropriate style you are happy to use for these then you can list the publications you want using `\nocite{}` and these will then be in the bibliography for the article/CV/... without the need for visible citations.

Comment: With BibLaTeX, the bibliography is printed wherever you put the `\printbibliography` command. BibTeX, I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would also recommend to use `biblatex` instead of bibtex. Please find some info how to switch [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex). It allows the use of `\fullcite`, which is great. It puts a single reference anywhere in the text. Therefore, it is ideal for grant proposals and cv, where you might need your 'five most important publications' or something like that. I made a small example:

[image: example text]

The latex file is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{manuell.bib}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

I made the following publication when I was very young:
\begin{itemize}
\item \fullcite{Reynolds:1950p3730}
\end{itemize}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

and the `.bib`-file:

```
@article{Reynolds:1950p3730,
author = {C Reynolds and B Serin and W Wright and L Nesbitt}, 
journal = {Phys. Rev.},
title = {Superconductivity of isotopes of mercury},
pages = {487},
doi = {10.1063/1.3332575},
volume = {78},
year = {1950},
URL = {http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRev.78.487}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the biblatex package. I think that's exactly the sort of thing that I needed.